# method not triggered on click after loading in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have this method that is called on page load and then when i create a button in my html to call the same method. I am not seeing the change i am expecting.
I have a list of songs and when the user clicks the shuffle button it should shuffle the list of songs..

currently on page load i have

```
public musicList = [];

public ngOnInit(){
  this.shufflePlaylist();
}

public shufflePlaylist(){
....code...
}

public shuffleBtnClick(){
   this.shufflePlaylist();
}
```

in my html i have:

```
<ul *ngFor="let song of musicList">
<li>{{song}}</li>
</ul>
```

click function:

```
<span (click)="shuffleBtnClick()">shuffle</span>
```

Am i missing a type of binding that is needed to update my songs list upon shuffleBtnClick?

Comment: Where is the HTML for your shuffle button?

Comment: Could you create a plnkr example to show the problem?

Comment: where are you binding the click event with the method "shuffleBtnClick"?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery i went ahead and added the missing html for the click.

Comment: @lpradhap added missing html to show click function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your issue is with change detection. Add the below updates and test and see if it fixes ur issue.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
   private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

public shufflePlaylist(){
    ....code...
    this._cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

The above code forces the angular engine to check for change detection which would identify your array update.